# HTML5 doctype and WAP mobile browsers

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-website, doctype, wap

Does anyone know if the HTML5 doctype is supported in WAP mobile browsers or legacy devices? Has anyone even tried using the HTML5 doctypes for pre Webkit browsers? If so what was were the issues involved in displaying your page in legacy browsers?

Comment: do you mean wml only phones/browsers?

Comment: Pretty much any pre-smartphone mobile phones. WML would count. Just trying to get some general info.

Comment: phones that support only wml wouldn't work with html. I remember some old html capable phones having trouble with non valid xhtml but thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out WAP 2.0 can support XHTML-MP doctype which in turn became XHTML Basic 1.1 therefore the HTML5 doctype should be supported in WAP.